# Manually enter a value in django model form

Tags: python, django

I am using django's default `User` class. I have made a `UserImage` class to store users' images.

```
class UserImage(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False)
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/images/')
```

In the `ImageUploadForm` form, I only want user to chose the `image_url`, and set `user_id` to currently authenticated user's id. This is the image upload form,

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserImage
        fields = {'image_url'}
```

Normally I save model forms like this,

```
form = ProjectForm(request.POST or None, instance=project)

    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects:project_dashboard', kwargs={'project_id': project_id}))
```

So how do I include the `user_id` field here? Should I make this a hidden field in the view? Or is there a better choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the image will be uploaded by authenticated user,right? I mean only after login, he/she can upload image. 
In that case you can simply use `request.user` in your user parameter.

```
if form.is_valid():
   user_image = form.save(commit=False)
   user_image.user_id = request.user.id
   user_image.save()
```

Comment: but is it possible to use it like this, `form.user_id = request.user.id` without adding `user_id` in field list? if I add it I get a text field for entering `user_id`

Comment: I have updated the above comment the a sample code. You simply need to save data with commit=False for the first time so that you can update it later on.